# Date display/formatting in ejs-express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

So, I have a mysql table and one column has date data. I am creating a webpage and I want to display my tables. The result (with the code below) is this:
[image]

 I want for the data in the column display, to be something like 1 January 2021 or just 01/01/2021 for example.

And my code:

**passenger_index.ejs**

```
            <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Birthday</th>
                        <th>Sex</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <% passengers.forEach(function(passenger){ %>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= passenger.passenger_id %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= passenger.name %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= passenger.birthday %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= passenger.sex %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= passenger.email %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= passenger.phone %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <% }); %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**With this code, I execute my query**

```
exports.view = (req, res) => {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM passenger ORDER BY passenger_id";
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('passenger_index', {
            title: 'Passengers details',
            passengers: rows
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ejs part from:

```
 <%= passenger.birthday %>
```

to this (I needed a format suitable to my country:

```
<%= passenger.birthday.toLocaleDateString('el-GR') %>
```

And everything works fine now